# Backup approach in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While I understand that replication can be used for disaster recovery, Timetravel/failsafe to recover up to 90 to 97 days. I am curious on solution options in implementing backup approach beyond what time travel can offer based on below requirements

(1) Retain weekly/monthly/yearly snapshots of data to comply with various regulations
(2) Recover entire database to a back-in-time picture

While traditional databases offer flexibility in terms of backups for recovery, I am trying to understand any backup options beyond cloning and timetravel that customers use to facilitate snowflake back-in-time recovery options up to last 7 years.

Thanks for reading the post and any inputs that you may have.

Comment: You could always write to a stage (e.g s3) full table dumps in snappy-compressed parquet files.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html

Comment: Please can you explain why cloning would not meet your requirement? Thanks